# How do I change the color of an errormessage?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to get the "Voer het aankoopbedrag met komma in zoals deze op jouw kassabon staat, rond dit bedrag niet zelf af." in a different color (red). Can anyone help met out how to get this in a different color?

Thanks in advance!

```
    // Add validator to check orderamount
pristine.addValidator(
    document.getElementById("orderAmount"),
    function(value) {
        var pattOrderAmount = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1,3}\,[0-9]{2}$");
        console.log(value);
        if(pattOrderAmount.test(value)) {
          return true;
        } else {
           return false;
        }
    },
    "Voer het aankoopbedrag met komma in zoals deze op jouw kassabon staat, rond dit bedrag niet zelf af.",
    3,
    false);
```

This is where the output is created:

```
<!-- FORM ELEMENT END --> <!-- FORM ELEMENT START -->
<div class="form-element form-group"><label class="form-element__label form-element__label--top registration__form-input-label">Jouw aankoopbedrag<a style="font-size: 14px; color: red; float: right; text-decoration: none;" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#orderAmountModal">Meer info</a></label>
<div class="form-element__container">
<div class="input">
<div class="input__wrapper">
<div class="input__field"><input name="orderAmount" class="input__form-node" id="orderAmount" type="text" max="100" placeholder="0,00" value="" data-ref="orderAmount" data-pristine-max-message="Bedrag kan maximaal 100 euro zijn." /></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not without knowing about the `addValidator` function or knowing where it is being output.

Comment: This were the output is created:

Comment: You need to clarify where the output is going to be displayed. Is it in an HTML document? If so, what does the HTML markup look like?

Comment: It's not obvious how your string gets output anywhere! Could you create a [mcve] that highlights the issue you're having?

Comment: I've added the HTML element, does this clarify?

Comment: You need to define styling for your html element. This can be done in multiple ways. I suggest reading up about html and css. For instance here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_styles.asp

Comment: I see you have set the color to red `<a>` tag with the text "Meer info". You can do the same for any other element that you want the color of the text to be red.

Comment: Also, in the JS code you presented, we only see that you are calling the function `addValidator` and passing it 5 arguments, (1) an HTML element, (2) a function, (3) a string, (4) a number and (5) a boolean. But, we have no idea what the function does.